# Why this program is not running?

Tags: python

```
class bikeShop:
    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock

    def displayBike(self):
        print("Total Bikes", self.stock)

    def rentForBike(self, q):
        if q <= 0:
            print("Please Enter the value greater than zero")
        elif q > self.stock:
            print("Please Enter the less than the available stock")
        else:
            self.stock = self.stock - q
            print("Total price", q * 100)
            print("Total Bikes Available", self.stock)

    while True:
        obj = bikeShop(100)
        uc = int(input('''
    1. Display Stock
    2. Request a Bike For Rent (Price For One Bike is PKR.100/-)
    3. Exit      
                  '''))
        if uc == 1:
            obj.displayBike()
        elif uc == 2:
            n = int(input("Enter the Qty"))
            obj.rentForBike(n)
        else:
            break
```

It gives an error:

> NameError: name 'bikeShop' is not defined

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Python, but it looks like you're trying to execute a loop at the class definition level here? That doesn't make much sense. Try reducing the indentation of the entire `while` loop by one level.

Comment: "Why this program is not running?" is an awful subject line. Beyond that you seem to be unaware that leading whitespace matters for the syntax of Python programs.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```py
class bikeShop:
    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock

    def displayBike(self):
        print("Total Bikes", self.stock)

    def rentForBike(self, q):
        if q <= 0:
            print("Please Enter the value greater than zero")
        elif q > self.stock:
            print("Please Enter the less than the available stock")
        else:
            self.stock = self.stock - q
            print("Total price", q * 100)
            print("Total Bikes Available", self.stock)

while True:
    obj = bikeShop(100)
    uc = int(input('''
1. Display Stock
2. Request a Bike For Rent (Price For One Bike is PKR.100/-)
3. Exit      
              '''))
    if uc == 1:
        obj.displayBike()
    elif uc == 2:
        n = int(input("Enter the Qty"))
        obj.rentForBike(n)
    else:
        break
```

The while loop was inside the class, that was causing the issue.